# Is it possible to check if an interface is activated in pcap?

Tags: c++, assert, pcap, libpcap

I am making a basic packet sniffer using pcap.h.  While I was unit testing the function that called pcap_dispatch, I gave it non-activated interfaces and invalid interfaces.  pcap_dispatch return -3, and as far as the man pages for pcap_dispatch goes, it should only return -2, -1, or more, but never less.

Of course, I can just handle this -3 return value after pcap_dispatch returns, handling it as some obscure edge case, but I'd like to make sure that it doesn't ever return such a value.

I could do that with an assert only if I knew how to check if the interface is activated.  So, does anyone know it?

---

```
pcap_t *null_iface = NULL;
pcap_t *not_act = pcap_create( "valid", errmsg );
pcap_t *act = pcap_create( "valid", errmsg );
    pcap_activate( act );
pcap_t *not_act_inv = pcap_create( "invalid", errmsg );
pcap_t *act_inv = pcap_create( "invalid", errmsg );
    pcap_activate( act );
pcap_t *ifaces[ 5 ] = {
    null_iface, not_act, act, not_act_inv, act_inv 
    };

for ( int a = 0; a < 5; a++ ) {
    result = pcap_dispatch( iface[ a ], 1, handler, NULL );
    // if one    - got one
    // elif zero - got nothing
    // elif -1   - error ( doesn't fire, by the way )
    // elif -2   - I manually stopped it
    // else      - impossible - but the assert fires
    //           - printing result is -3
    //           - for not_act, not_act_inv, and act_inv
    else {
        assert( false );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to check if an interface is activated in pcap?

Yes.  You check by looking at the return value of `pcap_activate()`.  The `pcap_activate()` man page says:

> `pcap_activate()` returns 0 on success without warnings, `PCAP_WARNING_PROMISC_NOTSUP` on success on a device that doesn't support promiscuous mode if promiscuous mode was requested, `PCAP_WARNING` on success with any other warning, `PCAP_ERROR_ACTIVATED` if the handle has already been activated, `PCAP_ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVICE` if the capture source specified when the handle was created doesn't exist, `PCAP_ERROR_PERM_DENIED` if the process doesn't have permission to open the capture source, `PCAP_ERROR_RFMON_NOTSUP` if monitor mode was specified but the capture source doesn't support monitor mode, `PCAP_ERROR_IFACE_NOT_UP` if the capture source is not up, and `PCAP_ERROR` if another error occurred.  If `PCAP_WARNING` or `PCAP_ERROR` is returned, `pcap_geterr()` or `pcap_perror()` may be called with *p* as an argument to fetch or display a message describing the warning or error.  If  `PCAP_WARNING_PROMISC_NOTSUP`, `PCAP_ERROR_NO_SUCH_DEVICE`, or `PCAP_ERROR_PERM_DENIED` is returned, `pcap_geterr()` or `pcap_perror()` may be called with *p* as an argument to fetch or display an message giving additional details about the problem that might be useful for debugging the problem if  it's unexpected.

You should also be checking whether `pcap_create()` returns NULL, by the way.